# c++ sstream,reading different amount of variables per line

Tags: c++, sstream

I am trying to read a text file with different amount of variables on each line and set the correct values to a vector using sstream.

```
/*Example file
 "f 1 2 3"
 "f 4 5 6 7"  */

ifstream infile(file);
string line;
char a;
int i=0;v,x,y,z;

while(getline(infile,line))
{
    istringstream iss(line)

    if(line[0]=='f')
    {       
         if(iss>> a >> v >> x >> y) 
         {    
              poly[i].face[0]=v;
              poly[i].face[1]=x;
              poly[i].face[2]=y;
              poly[i].four=false;
         }
         else if(iss>> a >> v >> x >> y >> z) //this doesn't seem to get called, ever.
         {
              poly[i].face[0]=v;
              poly[i].face[1]=x;
              poly[i].face[2]=y;
              poly[i].face[3]=z;
              poly[i].four=true;
         }
        poly.push_back(Poly());
        i++;
    }

}
```

code works for lines with 3 variables, but not for lines with 4 variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the first bunch of input already read those variables in successfully, and the `else` part was never reached.  Since the start of the line is always the same, as is where you store those values, you can do this:

```
 if(iss >> a >> v >> x >> y) 
 {    
      poly[i].face[0]=v;
      poly[i].face[1]=x;
      poly[i].face[2]=y;
      poly[i].four=false;

      if(iss >> z)
      {
          poly[i].face[3]=z;
          poly[i].four=true;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `>>` advances the stream, so it will change what the next call to `>>` does. If the first `if(...)` fails, the stream `iss` will have been modified so that the `else if (...)` fails too.

Instead, you can do something like this:

```
if(iss >> a >> v >> x >> y) 
{    
      poly[i].face[0]=v;
      poly[i].face[1]=x;
      poly[i].face[2]=y;

      if (iss >> z) // if we can read the fourth value...
      {
          poly[i].face[3]=z;
          poly[i].four=true;
      }
      else
      {
          poly[i].four=false;
      }
}
```